# How to summarise grouped value increases

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Utt = c(rep("oh", 10), rep("ah", 10)),
  name = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 10),
  value = c(0.5,2,2,2,2,1,0,1,3.5,1,
            2.2,2.3,1.9,0.1,0.3,1.8,3,4,3.5,2)
)
```

I need to know whether within in each group of `Utt` and `name`, there are **continuous `value` increases** and how large these increases are.

**EDIT**: I've cobbled together this code, which produces the right result but seems convoluted:

```
df %>%
  # order by name:
  arrange(name) %>%
  group_by(name, Utt) %>%
  # mutate:
  mutate(
    # is there an increase from one value to the next?
    is_increase = ifelse(lag(value) < value, value, NA),
    # what's the difference between these values?
    diff = is_increase - lag(value)) %>%
  group_by(name, Utt, grp = rleid(!is.na(diff))) %>%
  # sum the contiguous values:
  summarise(increase_size = sum(diff, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  # remove 0 values:
  filter(!increase_size == 0) %>%
  # put same-group increase_sizes in the same row:
  summarise( 
            increase_size = str_c(increase_size, collapse = ', '))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [2]
  name  Utt   increase_size
  <chr> <chr> <chr>        
1 A     ah    3.2          
2 A     oh    1.5, 3.5     
3 B     ah    3.9
```

NOTE: **Ideally**, the expected outcome would be:

```
1 A     ah    3.2          
2 A     oh    1.5, 3.5     
3 B     ah    3.9 
4 B     oh     NA
```

Is there a better (i.e., more concise, more clever) `dplyr` solution?

Comment: several questions for clarification - 1) Is there any inherent order provided by another variable or are you trusting R to keep the order as is? (which I would not!!!) 2) What exactly do you mean with continuous increase? Only increasing values? Any increase over more than n rows? Only increase of a equal amount?

Comment: only increasing values, e.g., 1,2,3,4 but not 1,2,0,3,4; amount of increase not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, my solution was similar to yours. One possible modification might be to subset your columns before summing instead of filtering. This will keep all combinations of `name` and `Utt` and allow for `NA` for `increase_size` in the end. Since the column `increase_size` is character type, you can convert an empty string to `NA`.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  group_by(name, Utt) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(0, diff(value))) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(diff < 0), .add = T) %>%
  summarise(increase_size = sum(diff[diff > 0], na.rm = T)) %>%
  group_by(name, Utt) %>%
  summarise(increase_size = toString(increase_size[increase_size > 0])) %>%
  mutate(increase_size = na_if(increase_size, ""))
```

**Output**

```
  name  Utt   increase_size
  <chr> <chr> <chr>        
1 A     ah    3.2          
2 A     oh    1.5, 3.5     
3 B     ah    3.9          
4 B     oh    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to find what you want.

```
f <- function(x) {
    ind <- which(x > lag(x))
    if (length(ind) == 0) {
        return(NA)
    }
    ind2 <- ind[which(lead(ind, default = max(ind) + 2) - ind > 1)]
    ind1 <- ind[which(ind - lag(ind, default = min(ind) - 2) > 1)] - 1
    return(paste0(x[ind2] - x[ind1], collapse = ", "))
}
```

And use the function in summarise:

```
df %>% group_by(name, Utt) %>% summarise(increase = f(value))
```